# How to change the variable to find in a FOR/DO statement | Batch

Tags: batch-file

How would I change the variable that I look for in a For/Do Statement.

```
@ECHO off
set Riddle=The Bird In The The Bush
SET /a count=0
FOR (The) IN (%Riddle%) DO SET /a count=%count%+1
ECHO %count%
```

In this case "The" is the variable that I desire to look for,
But I don't think that's the correct formatting

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: it seems you want the counting of the occurences of a substring inside a string. Unfortunately for you, batch is not the most appropriate scripting language for this kind of task. You'll have to pipe the output of `ECHO`ing the variable thru a line splitter and its output piped again to `FIND /C`.  Good luck.

Comment: So Which language would you reccommend?

Comment: Python is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is functional version of your code

```
@ECHO off
set Riddle=The Bird In The The Bush
SET /a count=0
FOR %%a IN (%Riddle%) DO if "%%~a"=="The" SET /a count+=1
ECHO %count%
```

Note this is case sensitive. To make it non sensitive replace `if "%%~a"` with `if /i "%%~a"`.